# Interviewstreet's Insertion sort program

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I tried to program Interiewstreet's Insertion sort challenge [Link for the challenge](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4e90477dbd22b) 
in Python and here is my code shown below.

The program runs fine for a limit(which I'm not sure of) of input elements, but returns a false output for inputs of larger sizes. Can anyone guide me what am I doing wrong?

```
# This program tries to identify number of times swapping is done to sort the input array 

"""
=>Get input values and print them
=>Get number of test cases and get inputs for those test cases
=>Complete Insertion sort routine
=>Add a variable to count the swapping's 
"""

def sort_swap_times(nums):
  """ This function takes a list of elements and then returns the number of times 
      swapping was necessary to complete the sorting
  """

  times_swapped = 0L
  # perform the insertion sort routine
  for j in range(1, len(nums)):
    key = nums[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i >= 0 and nums[i] > key:
      # perform swap and update the tracker
      nums[i + 1] = nums[i]
      times_swapped += 1
      i = i - 1
    # place the key value in the position identified
    nums[i + 1] = key

  return times_swapped


# get the upper limit.
limit = int(raw_input())  
swap_count = []

# get the length and elements.
for i in range(limit):
  length = int(raw_input())
  elements_str = raw_input() # returns a list of strings

  # convert the given elements from str to int
  elements_int = map(int, elements_str.split())

  # pass integer elements list to perform the sorting
  # get the number of times swapping was needed and append the return value to swap_count list
  swap_count.append(sort_swap_times(elements_int))


# print the swap counts for each input array
for x in swap_count:
  print x
```

Comment: gives wrong output if **which** integer has larger value?

Comment: @izomorphius, The site contains a list of test cases to run on the program

Comment: What do you mean by false outputs - TLE or WA?

Comment: @I got TLE error messages and only a few test cases passed

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is correct, but this is a naive approach to the problem and will give you a Time Limit Exceed signal on large test cases (i.e., len(nums) > 10000). Let's analyze the run-time complexity of your algorithm.

```
for j in range(1, len(nums)):
    key = nums[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i >= 0 and nums[i] > key:
      # perform swap and update the tracker
      nums[i + 1] = nums[i]
      times_swapped += 1
      i = i - 1
    # place the key value in the position identified
    nums[i + 1] = key
```

The number of steps required in the above snippet is proportional to 1 + 2 + .. + len(nums)-1, or len(nums)*(len(nums)-1)/2 steps, which is O(len(nums)^2).

**Hint**:

Use the fact that all values will be within [1,10^6]. What you are really doing here is finding the number of inversions in the list, i.e. find all pairs of i < j s.t. nums[i] > nums[j]. Think of a data structure that allows you to find the number of swaps needed for each insert operation in logarithmic time complexity. Of course, there are other approaches.

**Spoiler**:

> [Binary Indexed Trees](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees)